# Jest throws exception when running without root permission

Tags: reactjs, node.js, jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I have a trouble with Jest on my Typescript React project.

Node: 16.10.0
Jest: 26.6.3
Babel-jest: 26.6.3

When I run command `jest <file-name` to execute a test on a file, I get the error message with stacktrace like this:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/<username>/<my_project>/test/jest.setup.ts:11
    import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
```

It seems like the `babel-jest` transformer cannot load the typescript file with esm6 module.
I realize this happens globally to all projects in my machine, other teammates don't.
Especially, this issue does not occurs when I run with `sudo` permission.

These are some actions I tried:

- Removing all `node_modules` and reinstalled.
- Reinstalled Node
- Change owner of some suspected folders and files. Like global node_module from root -> current user.
- Add `type: module` to package.json.